# Title of the theorem

Tags: formatting, theorems

in my paper the text inside theorem is *italic* while the word **Theorem 1** is bold and not italic. I would like to have a title of the theorem also not italic. The example is here:

**Theorem 1.** (The title) *Let the set...*

How can I do it? I tried to type
`\begin{theorem}{title here}`
but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Usually

```
\begin{theorem}[The title]
Some statement
\end{theorem}
```

should do what you want. The standard LaTeX setting prints in boldface also the title, which doesn't happen when **amsthm** is loaded.

Comment: @Gortaur: with default settings also the title would be bold.

Comment: @Stefan Not with **amsthm**, which I prefer.

Comment: @egreg: I prefer it too. It just hasn't been mentioned in the question, so I tested without.

Answer (score 4):

You might like to test 
   `\newtheorem{theorem}{\textit{Theorem}}`
before `\begin{document}` then 
    `\begin{theorem} 
     Some statement 
    \end{theorem}`

Comment: But where the title?

Comment: In pre-definition of \newtheorem{theorem}{bloh,bloh} whatever you put as {bloh,bloh} comes in place of your title "Theorem 1" you mentioned as bold face (except the counter). You do not need to use \begin{theorem}[The Title]. Just \begin{theorem}  is enough, then. [You can format counter of theorems by, say,  \numberwithin{theorem}{section}].

Comment: You also might like to test this "\newtheorem{theorem}{\large T\small\textit{heorem}}"