# How to make the optional title of a theorem bold with amsthm?

Tags: fonts, formatting, theorems, amsthm

I use the code mentioned in [Title of the theorem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22223/title-of-the-theorem):

```
\begin{theorem}[The title]
Some statement
\end{theorem}
```

However with `amsthm` the optional title -- above: "The title" -- is neither **bold** nor *italic*, but (ordinary) roman. I prefer to work with `amsthm`, so how can I solve the problem?

---

Update: After applying the code

```
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}%                % Name
  {}%                                     % Space above
  {}%                                     % Space below
  {\itshape}%                                     % Body font
  {}%                                     % Indent amount
  {\bfseries}%                            % Theorem head font
  {.}%                                    % Punctuation after theorem head
  { }%                                    % Space after theorem head, ' ', or \newline
  {}%                                     % Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')

\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[abcd]\label{firstlabel}%
111
\end{theorem}
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

The content in the bracket is still not **bold**. How can I change it?

It can be solved by

```
\begin{theorem}[\bfseries abcd]\label{firstlabel}%
111
\end{theorem}
```

although I'd like to have it set universally.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can put this in the preamble, without the need to define new theorem styles; in fact this redefines the `plain` and `definition` theorem styles in order that the theorem title has the same font attributes as the theorem heading:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\makeatletter
\def\th@plain{%
  \thm@notefont{}% same as heading font
  \itshape % body font
}
\def\th@definition{%
  \thm@notefont{}% same as heading font
  \normalfont % body font
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: How can you use this setup to make the heading font and the optional theorem title italicized?

Comment: @fctaylor25 Add `\thm@headfont{\itshape}`.

Answer (score 18):

This can be solved by using the final argument of `\newtheoremstyle`.  It has an unusual format that is the content of a three argument command for printing the title heading.  To get the name, number and optional title you make it be

```
\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}
```

which is essentially the standard definition

```
\def\thmhead@plain#1#2#3{%
  \thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
  \thmnote{ {\the\thm@notefont(#3)}}}
```

with the font switching commands used removed.

In your example it would look like

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}%                % Name
  {}%                                     % Space above
  {}%                                     % Space below
  {\itshape}%                                     % Body font
  {}%                                     % Indent amount
  {\bfseries}%                            % Theorem head font
  {.}%                                    % Punctuation after theorem head
  { }%                                    % Space after theorem head, ' ', or \newline
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}}%                                     % Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')

\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

Some text before.

\begin{theorem}[Our hero]\label{firstlabel}%
  The most amazing result you have seen.
\end{theorem}


And some text after.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 16):

Here's a complete MWE with description using the `amsthm` package, see section 4.3 of the documentation for more details

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}%                % Name
  {}%                                     % Space above
  {}%                                     % Space below
  {\itshape}%                             % Body font
  {}%                                     % Indent amount
  {\bfseries}%                            % Theorem head font
  {.}%                                    % Punctuation after theorem head
  { }%                                    % Space after theorem head, ' ', or \newline
  {}%                                     % Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')

\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
\lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This code doesn't seem to affect the font attributes of the optional theorem title -- "The title" in the OP's example.

Comment: @Mico Indeed! Thanks for clarifying. In which case, I think @egreg's solution is the way to go. `ntheorem` does what the OP wants by default

Answer (score 8):

Another solution employs the `xpatch` package, and its command `xpatchcmd`, to modify the internal command `\@thm` of the `amsthm` package. With the modification, illustrated in the MWE below, the optional title always uses the same font as is used in the rest of the (theorem, definition, remark) header.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch,amsthm}
\makeatletter
   \xpatchcmd{\@thm}{\fontseries\mddefault\upshape}{}{}{} % same font as thm-header
\makeatother
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}[Pythagoras]
Suppose that \ldots
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks! I had the same problem as the original poster but I used a custom theorem style. This solution works independently from the theorem style so it's much appreciated :)

Comment: @Christian: I'm delighted to learn that my code works for your custom theorem style as well. I would venture a guess that this theorem style is either based on or closely patterned after those in the `amsthm` package. :-)

Comment: Oh, please excuse the misunderstanding. Sure, it uses `amsthm` but the accepted answer AFAICS still doesn't work for arbitrary styles created with `\newtheoremstyle` but your does :)