# How do I remove parentheses from theorem optional argument?

Tags: formatting, theorems, brackets, amsthm, optional-arguments

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts, amsthm, amsmath, amssymb}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\newtheorem*{Pythagorean theorem}{Pythagorean theorem}

%=======

\begin{document}

\begin{Pythagorean theorem}[\cite{Pythagoras}]
This is Pythagoras' theorem.
\end{Pythagorean theorem}

%===

\begin{thebibliography}{HD}

\bibitem[1]{Pythagoras}
Pythagoras' theorem.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

If I use

```
\newtheorem*{Pythagorean theorem}{Pythagorean theorem}
```

plus

```
\begin{Pythagorean theorem}[\cite{Pythagoras}]
This is Pythagoras' theorem.
\end{Pythagorean theorem}
```

I get the following:

> **Pythagorean theorem** ([1])**.** This is Pythagoras' theorem.

My question is: how do I remove the parenthesis around [1]?

In order words, I want LaTeX to display the following:

> **Pythagorean theorem** [1]**.** This is Pythagoras' theorem.

Note that the first period in the sentence above must be in boldface.

Comment: What about `\begin{Pythagorean theorem~\cite{Pythagoras}}`

Comment: @Dox Thank you for your comment. I've just tried that and I get the following error: `! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.14 \begin{Pythagorean theorem~\cite{Pythagoras}}
                                                  
?`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to update the way the theorem header is set, since it includes `( )` by default (taken from [`amsclass.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/amscls/amsclass.dtx)):

```
\def\thmhead@plain#1#2#3{%
  \thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
  \thmnote{ {\the\thm@notefont(#3)}}}
\let\thmhead\thmhead@plain
```

Note the use of `(#3)` above. So, we copy-and-paste the above definition with the adjustment:

```
\makeatletter
\def\thmhead@plain#1#2#3{%
  \thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
  \thmnote{ {\the\thm@notefont#3}}}
\let\thmhead\thmhead@plain
\makeatother
```

This just has the `( )` removed. Here's a MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm

\makeatletter
\def\thmhead@plain#1#2#3{%
  \thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
  \thmnote{ {\the\thm@notefont#3}}}
\let\thmhead\thmhead@plain
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\newtheorem*{Pythagorean theorem}{Pythagorean theorem}

\expandafter\show\csname Pythagorean theorem\endcsname
%=======

\begin{document}

\begin{Pythagorean theorem}[\cite{Pythagoras}]
This is Pythagoras' theorem.
\end{Pythagorean theorem}

%===

\begin{thebibliography}{HD}

\bibitem[1]{Pythagoras}
Pythagoras' theorem.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

A somewhat simpler solution is provided via an [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) patch:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\patchcmd{\thmhead}{(#3)}{#3}{}{}
```

Comment: I spent much time searching for information on the web and trying to figure out how to fix the problem. This answer definitely fixed it. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: It took me a while to notice that if you use swapped numbers then you need to redefine \swappedhead@plain as well