# How to avoid parentheses + brackets in the title in amsthm when only using \cite?

Tags: formatting, theorems, amsthm

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174304/how-do-i-remove-parentheses-from-theorem-optional-argument) and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52621/how-to-remove-brackets-from-the-optional-title-in-amsthm). Basically, I would like to avoid the sequence ([...]) in theorem's optional arguments, as shown below:

[image]

To obtain this result, as suggested by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52626/34905), I used the `\patchcmd` macro of the `etoolbox` package. However, I have to switch from
`\patchcmd{\thmhead}{(#3)}{#3}{}{}`
to
`\patchcmd{\thmhead}{#3}{(#3)}{}{}` on every change, which is not very convenient for a large book with many theorems. Thus I was wondering whether a single command would be possible. Note that I am using the two forms `\cite{}` and `\cite[]{}`, which makes things a bit more complex.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[]{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}   
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
    
\begin{document}

\section{Pythagoras' theorem}

\noindent Correct versions:

\begin{theorem}[Pythagoras]
  $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Pythagoras, \cite{Pythagoras}]
  $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Pythagoras, {\cite[p.\ 345]{Pythagoras}}]
  $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.
\end{theorem}

\patchcmd{\thmhead}{(#3)}{#3}{}{}

\begin{theorem}[\cite{Pythagoras}]
  $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[{\cite[p.\ 21]{Pythagoras}}]
  $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.
\end{theorem}

\noindent To be avoided:

\patchcmd{\thmhead}{#3}{(#3)}{}{}

\begin{theorem}[\cite{Pythagoras}]
  $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[{\cite[p.\ 21]{Pythagoras}}]
  $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{thebibliography}{HD}

\bibitem[1]{Pythagoras}
Pythagoras' theorem.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not just have the citation as the first thing within the theorem? This also has the added benefit of not having a strange bold full stop after non-bold text.

Comment: @oliversm one reason to use the optional argument is that it is printed in the List of Theorems (`\listoftheorems`).

Comment: And why not a `\footcite`?

Comment: @Marijn, Having something like a named theorem in the list of theorems is useful, but having a naked numeric citation I can't imagine being desirable in the list of theorems.

Comment: @oliversm Isn't the bold full stop the default behaviour of the optional argument (See Theorem 1.1) ? Anyway, your comment is not relevant to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match the argument against a regular expression that represents `\cite` followed by zero or one occurrence of `[...]` and by `{...}`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[]{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}   

% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17555/4427 for the parameters
\newtheoremstyle{jepinplain}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\itshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{{\normalfont\ \checkcite{#3}}}} % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\checkcite}{m}
 {
  \regex_match:nnTF {\A \c{cite}(?:\[[^]]*\])?\{.*\} \Z} { #1 }
   {% only \cite
    #1
   }
   { (#1) }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\theoremstyle{jepinplain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
    
\begin{document}

\section{Pythagoras' theorem}

\noindent Correct versions:

\begin{theorem}
  $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Pythagoras]
  $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Pythagoras, \cite{Pythagoras}]
  $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Pythagoras, {\cite[p.\ 345]{Pythagoras}}]
  $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[\cite{Pythagoras}]
  $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[{\cite[p.\ 21]{Pythagoras}}]
  $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem[1]{Pythagoras}
Pythagoras' theorem.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

A new theorem style is better, unless you want to modify the standard `\thmhead` command.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little old now, but I was addressing the same issue so thought I'd post how I did it. It would be nice to somehow be able to just flag whether parentheses should be added or not, but I worked around it manually.

Solution 0:

Leave the amendment in place permanently, and add your own parentheses.

```tex
\patchcmd{\thmhead}{(#3)}{#3}{}{}

\begin{theorem}[(Pythagoras)]
  $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.
\end{theorem}
    
\begin{theorem}[(Pythagoras, \cite{Pythagoras})]
  $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[\cite{Pythagoras}]
  $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.
\end{theorem}
```

Of course, this loses part of the benefit of LaTeX macros, that you can redefine an appearance in one place and have it apply everywhere -- if you suddenly decide to bracket the theorem notes some other way, you'd have to go through and manually change them all. So a tiny improvement is:

Solution 1:

Define a macro.

```tex
\patchcmd{\thmhead}{(#3)}{#3}{}{}
\newcommand{\notewrap}[1]{(#1)}

\begin{theorem}[\notewrap{Pythagoras}]
  $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.
\end{theorem}
    
\begin{theorem}[\notewrap{Pythagoras, \cite{Pythagoras}}]
  $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[\cite{Pythagoras}]
  $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.
\end{theorem}
```