# Problem with amsthm

Tags: amsthm

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
  \def\th@definition{
  \thm@notefont{}
  \bfseries}
\makeatother

\newtheoremstyle{definition}{2.5em}{2.5em}{}{}{\bfseries}{}{1em}{}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{defn}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{defn}[Optional Title] Definition content.
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```

I want to keep the updated definition style, but have the optional title in bold. The first few lines of code (`makeatletter ... makeatother`) accomplish this for the default definition, but they stop working when I try to modify the definition style. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` update precedes `\newtheoremstyle{definition}`, which overwrites your `\th@definition`. So, technically, the former construct is useless. So what do you mean by "updated definition style"?

Comment: presumably this uses the technique described in an answer to the question [How to make the optional title of a theorem bold with amsthm?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43966/579).  you're redefining the `definition` theorem style *after* that, as noted by @Werner, so if you stick with this definition, you should reverse the order.  but it would really be better if you did *not* redefine an existing style -- that will only confuse someone else if they have to look at it later.

Comment: I tried reversing the order and renaming the theorem styles, but it didn't work. What solution would you suggest?

Comment: I have now provided another answer to the linked question that may be more helpful to you.