# How to get the theorem name in the same font as `theorem'

Tags: fonts, theorems

When writing a theorem with some name I use the command,

```
\begin{theorem}[Paramjit] 
    Hello there I am Paramjit 
\end{theorem}
```

And this is what I get.
[image]

How to change the font of the name of the theorem. I want the brackets also to be bold. So just naming the theorem \textsc{Paramjit} is not an option. Currently I am writing the name of the theorem in the content of the theorem itself.

Comment: if you are using `amsthm`, this gives an answer: [How to make the optional title of a theorem bold with amsthm?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43966)

Comment: Please, add a minimal example

Comment: What do you mean by a minimal example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the default with `ntheorem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[thmmarks, thref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries\scshape\upshape}%
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\theoremseparator{.}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{A first section}

\begin{theorem}[Paramjit]\label{Para}
  Hello there I am Paramjit.%
\end{theorem}
This was \cref{Para}.

\end{document}
```

[image]