# Change the font size of the word "Theorem"

Tags: formatting, theorems

What should I do if I want to change the font size of the word "Theorem" but not of the body of the theorem? It doesn't seem that \newtheoremstyle has a parameter for this. It is probably  a rather weird request, but I do need the font of the word "theorem" to be a bit smaller in this case...

Comment: You can define a new theorem style with `amsthm`. [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/318281/14757) could be helfpul.

Comment: `ntheorem` has the  `\headerfont` and `\bodyfont` commands.

Comment: You can also use `\newtheorem{theorem}{\footnotesize Theorem}` or something similar.