# Get thmtools style with mdframed (issues with the title and MWE provided)

Tags: mdframed, thmtools

I am trying to achieve the following output with `mdframed`, but I can't. I did the proof in the attached picture below with `thmtools`, but I am abandoning it because some of my proofs are very long and I want them to be split between pages to avoid getting to large white spaces at the end of some pages (something that apparently thmtools cannot handle easily). What I can get is this:

[image: OBTAINED OUTPUT]

But the output I am trying to replicate should look as follows:

[image: DESIRED OUTPUT]

As you can see, what I need is:

(a) The title in the same line as the text.

(b) The word "Proof" before the name of the theorem being proven.

(c) A long horizontal dash between Proof and the title of the theorem being proven.

(d) A colon after the title of the theorem being proven.

Does it make sense? Here you can find a MWE that replicates what I get (except the font and the color of the math; because those are irrelevant to my question and would only make a code more complex without need).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools, amsthm, mathrsfs, amssymb}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax
\newmdenv[linecolor=Gray,frametitle=Proof]{proof}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}[frametitle={\textbf{von-Neumann--Morgenstern Expected Utility Theorem I}}]
Let's prove that if there exists $U: \mathcal{L}(X) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, a preference $\succsim$ on $\mathcal{L}(X)$ satisfies X and Y. Assume there exists a utility function $U: \mathcal{L}(X) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ representing $\succsim$ such that $U$ satisfies the expected utility property.
\begin{enumerate}
    \item To show that $\succsim$ \textbf{is continuous}, let $x,y,z \in \mathcal{L}(X)$ such that $x \succ y \succ z$. Since $U$ represents $\succsim$, $U(x) > U(y) > U(z)$. The set of real numbers is convex; and hence there exists $p \in (0,1)$ such that $p \cdot U(x) + (1-p) \cdot U(z) = U(y)$. By the expected utility property, $U(p \odot x \oplus (1-p) \odot z) = p \cdot U(x) + (1-p) \cdot U(z) = U(y)$. Since $U$ represents $\succsim$, $p \odot x \oplus (1-p) \odot z \sim y$. Now, let $q,r \in [0,1]$ be such that $q >p>r$. Then:
    \begin{flalign*}
        && q \cdot U(x) + (1-q) \cdot U(z) & > p \cdot U(x) + (1-p) \cdot U(z)\\
        && &> r \cdot U(x) + (1-r)\cdot U(z)
    \end{flalign*}

    And by the expected utility property, and the hypothesis that $U$ represents $\succsim$, it follows that $q \odot x \oplus (1-q) \odot z \succ y \succ r \odot x \oplus (1-r) \odot z$.
    \item To show that $\succsim$ \textbf{satisfies independence}, let $x,y,z \in \mathcal{L}(X)$ and let $p \in [0,1]$. Since $U$ represents $\succsim$, $x \succ y \Longleftrightarrow U(x) > U(y)$. Hence, $x \succ y \Longleftrightarrow p \cdot U(x) + (1-p) \cdot U(z) > p \cdot U(y) + (1-p) \cdot U(z)$. Since $U$ satisfies the expected utility property, $x \succ y \Longleftrightarrow [p \odot x \oplus (1-p) \odot z] \succ [p \odot y \oplus (1-p) \odot z]$. Since $U$ represents $\succsim$, $x \sim y \Longleftrightarrow U(X) = U(y)$. Hence, $x \sim y \Longleftrightarrow p \cdot U(x) + (1-p) \cdot U(z) = p \cdot U(y) + (1-p) \cdot U(z)$. Since $U$ satisfies the expected utility property, $x \sim y \Longleftrightarrow [p \odot x \oplus (1-p) \odot z] \sim [p \odot y \oplus (1-p) \odot z]$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Could anybody help me, please? Thank you all in advance for your time.

Comment: Can you make a compilable MWE? `\begin{document}` is in the wrong place and after moving it I get `Environment proof undefined. \begin{proof}`

Comment: I am really sorry for the mistake. It is fixed now and the MWE should compile just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bit of help from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185168/36296:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}%                % Name
  {0pt}%                                     % Space above
  {}%                                     % Space below
  {\itshape}%                             % Body font
  {}%                                     % Indent amount
  {\bfseries}%                            % Theorem head font
  {:}%                                    % Punctuation after theorem head
  { }%                                    % Space after theorem head, ' ', or \newline
  {\thmname{#1} -- \thmnote{#3}}%       % Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')
\theoremstyle{mystyle}

\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax

\newmdtheoremenv[innerleftmargin=0.1cm,innerrightmargin=0.1cm,innertopmargin=0.1cm,innerbottommargin=0.1cm]{proof}{Proof}

\AtEndEnvironment{proof}{\hfill$\square$}%

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}[von-Neumann--Morgenstern Expected Utility Theorem I]
Let's prove that if there exists $U: \mathcal{L}(X) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, a preference $\succsim$ on $\mathcal{L}(X)$ satisfies X and Y. Assume there exists a utility function $U: \mathcal{L}(X) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ representing $\succsim$ such that $U$ satisfies the expected utility property.
\begin{enumerate}
    \item To show that $\succsim$ \textbf{is continuous}, let $x,y,z \in \mathcal{L}(X)$ such that $x \succ y \succ z$. Since $U$ represents $\succsim$, $U(x) > U(y) > U(z)$. The set of real numbers is convex; and hence there exists $p \in (0,1)$ such that $p \cdot U(x) + (1-p) \cdot U(z) = U(y)$. By the expected utility property, $U(p \odot x \oplus (1-p) \odot z) = p \cdot U(x) + (1-p) \cdot U(z) = U(y)$. Since $U$ represents $\succsim$, $p \odot x \oplus (1-p) \odot z \sim y$. Now, let $q,r \in [0,1]$ be such that $q >p>r$. Then:
    \begin{flalign*}
        && q \cdot U(x) + (1-q) \cdot U(z) & > p \cdot U(x) + (1-p) \cdot U(z)\\
        && &> r \cdot U(x) + (1-r)\cdot U(z)
    \end{flalign*}

    And by the expected utility property, and the hypothesis that $U$ represents $\succsim$, it follows that $q \odot x \oplus (1-q) \odot z \succ y \succ r \odot x \oplus (1-r) \odot z$.
    \item To show that $\succsim$ \textbf{satisfies independence}, let $x,y,z \in \mathcal{L}(X)$ and let $p \in [0,1]$. Since $U$ represents $\succsim$, $x \succ y \Longleftrightarrow U(x) > U(y)$. Hence, $x \succ y \Longleftrightarrow p \cdot U(x) + (1-p) \cdot U(z) > p \cdot U(y) + (1-p) \cdot U(z)$. Since $U$ satisfies the expected utility property, $x \succ y \Longleftrightarrow [p \odot x \oplus (1-p) \odot z] \succ [p \odot y \oplus (1-p) \odot z]$. Since $U$ represents $\succsim$, $x \sim y \Longleftrightarrow U(X) = U(y)$. Hence, $x \sim y \Longleftrightarrow p \cdot U(x) + (1-p) \cdot U(z) = p \cdot U(y) + (1-p) \cdot U(z)$. Since $U$ satisfies the expected utility property, $x \sim y \Longleftrightarrow [p \odot x \oplus (1-p) \odot z] \sim [p \odot y \oplus (1-p) \odot z]$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I will mark it as accepted because your code does exactly what I asked for, but notice that your code increases the space surrounding the text inside the frame, which is something I'd like to avoid. Also, I forgot to mention that the QED symbol should be automatically added in the environment. But this is my fault because I forgot to mention it in the original question.

Comment: @Héctor Please see my edit for adjusted margins.

Comment: @Héctor and the qed

Comment: The qed symbol should not be on a separate line.

Answer (score 1):

I propose a solution with the simpler `framed` environment option of `ntheorem`. One advantage is the automatic (and correct) placement of the qed symbol, even when the proof ends in a displayed equation. It is activated by the `thmmarks` option.

I redefined the `nonumberplain` predefined style under the name `myproof` so as to incorporate the emdash between the name of the environment and the optional argument, in the place of the pair of parentheses.

Also I obtain a better layout of the `enumerate` environment inside the frame with `enumitem`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{geometry}%
 \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools, mathrsfs, amssymb}
\usepackage{framed, enumitem} %
\usepackage[framed, thref, amsmath, thmmarks]{ntheorem} %
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{myproof}%
{\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip\labelsep ##1\theorem@separator]}%
{\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip \labelsep ##1~---~##3\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\mdseries}
\theoremseparator{:}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\square}}
\theoremstyle{myproof}
\newframedtheorem{proof}{Proof}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}[von\,Neumann-Morgenstern Expected Utility Theorem I]
Let's prove that if there exists $U: \mathcal{L}(X) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, a preference $\succsim$ on $\mathcal{L}(X)$ satisfies X and Y. Assume there exists a utility function $U: \mathcal{L}(X) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ representing $\succsim$ such that $U$ satisfies the expected utility property.
\begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=*]
    \item To show that $\succsim$ \textbf{is continuous}, let $x,y,z \in \mathcal{L}(X)$ such that $x \succ y \succ z$. Since $U$ represents $\succsim$, $U(x) > U(y) > U(z)$. The set of real numbers is convex; and hence there exists $p \in (0,1)$ such that $p \cdot U(x) + (1-p) \cdot U(z) = U(y)$. By the expected utility property, $U(p \odot x \oplus (1-p) \odot z) = p \cdot U(x) + (1-p) \cdot U(z) = U(y)$. Since $U$ represents $\succsim$, $p \odot x \oplus (1-p) \odot z \sim y$. Now, let $q,r \in [0,1]$ be such that $q >p>r$. Then:
    \begin{flalign*}
        && q \cdot U(x) + (1-q) \cdot U(z) & > p \cdot U(x) + (1-p) \cdot U(z)\\
        && &> r \cdot U(x) + (1-r)\cdot U(z)
    \end{flalign*}

    And by the expected utility property, and the hypothesis that $U$ represents $\succsim$, it follows that $q \odot x \oplus (1-q) \odot z \succ y \succ r \odot x \oplus (1-r) \odot z$.
    \item To show that $\succsim$ \textbf{satisfies independence}, let $x,y,z \in \mathcal{L}(X)$ and let $p \in [0,1]$. Since $U$ represents $\succsim$, $x \succ y \Longleftrightarrow U(x) > U(y)$. Hence, $x \succ y \Longleftrightarrow p \cdot U(x) + (1-p) \cdot U(z) > p \cdot U(y) + (1-p) \cdot U(z)$. Since $U$ satisfies the expected utility property, $x \succ y \Longleftrightarrow [p \odot x \oplus (1-p) \odot z] \succ [p \odot y \oplus (1-p) \odot z]$. Since $U$ represents $\succsim$, $x \sim y \Longleftrightarrow U(X) = U(y)$. Hence, $x \sim y \Longleftrightarrow p \cdot U(x) + (1-p) \cdot U(z) = p \cdot U(y) + (1-p) \cdot U(z)$. Since $U$ satisfies the expected utility property, $x \sim y \Longleftrightarrow [p \odot x \oplus (1-p) \odot z] \sim [p \odot y \oplus (1-p) \odot z]$.
\end{enumerate} %
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I really like your answer, thank you very much. I am about to ask a related question on how to get the numbering I was getting with `thmtools´ but with `mdframed´, instead. That is, CHAPTER.SECTION.ALPH for Definitions and CHAPTER.SECTION.ROMAN for Propositions, while keeping PROOFS unnumbered. I haven't been able to do so yet, but maybe I succeed with your code.

Comment: I'll try to see that. Do you mean `uppercase` Roman and Alph?

Comment: I mean exactly that. You can indeed see the question here, in case you want: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353923/how-to-use-mdframed-to-number-by-chapter-section-and-else-mwe?noredirect=1#comment870273_353923 (it just got an answer).

Comment: @Héctor: I've posted a solution to your new question using `ntheorem`.