# How to do {bold}Definition 1 (Graph){/bold}... in latex

Tags: formatting, theorems

I know how to do this:

[image]

where the **Definition 3** is bold. You just do this:

```
\newtheorem{def}{Definition}
...    
\begin{def}
A \textit{field} $\mathbb{F}$.
\end{def}
```

Wondering how to do it like this though:

[image]

where it has the name of the definition in bold to. Wondering if there is a function or something I could create to do this:

```
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition ([PARAMETER])}
...    
\begin{def[label="Field"]}
A \textit{field} $\mathbb{F}$.
\end{def}
```

Comment: please provide small but complete document with your definition. that we not need to write it from scratch :-). help us to help you!

Comment: likely duplicate: [How to make the optional title of a theorem bold with amsthm?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43966)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [`amsthm` documentation](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf) there is an example in 4.3.2 which shows how to do this:
You first define a new theoremstyle with a bold note:

```
\newtheoremstyle{bfnote}%
  {}{}
  {\itshape}{}
  {\bfseries}{.}
  { }{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}}
```

Then you activate it with

```
\theoremstyle{bfnote}
```

Now you can define your theorem (The name `def` is invalid here):

```
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}
```

In your document, you can use it like this:

```
\begin{defi}[Graph]
  A \textit{field} $\mathbb{F}$.
\end{defi}
```

[image]