# Space around theoremes

Tags: typography, newtheorem

I have defined a `newtheorem` style and I want to shift the theoreme a little bit below from the rest, but I don't get it right.
I have something like this :

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}



\newtheoremstyle{Marine}% name 
{3pt}% Space above 
{3pt}% Space below 
{}% Body font 
{}% Indent amount 
{}% Theorem head font
{:}% Punctuation after theorem head
{\newline}% Space after theorem head 
{\underline{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}}\thmnote{ \textcolor{red}{ (#3)}}}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)

\theoremstyle{Marine}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Code probably based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43966. If this is true, maybe indicate this in your question.

Comment: not exactly but thats the same approximately. Another user told me that the code is written in this way.

Comment: @MarineGalantin, please complete your example, so it compiles when we copy and compile it. It may also be a good idea to add a screenshot. Thank you