# An optional argument for theorem environment to attribute the author

Tags: theorems, newtheorem

How to define the theorem environment to make an attribution in the formulation. To use something like that

```
\thm[Lagrange]{...}
```

and obtain

**Theorem 3 (Lagrange).** {...}

I searched this site but to no avail.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! This is the standard behaviour, at least with packages `amsthm` or `ntheorem`.

Comment: Welcome.  The input should be `\begin{thm}[Lagrange]` if you are using `amsthm`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks a lot! Though it's strange to me that the type of (Lagrange) is not bold and the point at the end is.

Comment: @J.Doe -- That's AMS house style. If you want it bold, this question says how: [How to make the optional title of a theorem bold with amsthm?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43966)

Comment: It occurs to me that if you're using `amsthm`, it might be helpful for you to read the user's guide: `texdoc amsthdoc`.  It's not very long, and explains a lot about how things work as well as gives guidance for frequently requested variations.