# How do I put a number after a subheading?

Tags: amsmath, lists, enumerate, theorems

I'm new to overleaf so I'm using a template to make a list of Theorems, Definitions, Axioms, etc.
It looks pretty messy because it looks like this:

**Theorem 1.**

**Axiom 1.**

**Theorem 2.**

**Theorem 3.**

**Definition 1.**

here's my setup:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts} 
\usepackage{enumerate}%

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
```

how can I get it to be more organized to say

**Theorem 1:**

**Axiom 2:**

**Theorem 3:**

**Definition 4:** ...?

Also, when I add a name to something, for example,

```
\begin{definition}[Absolute Value]
```

it looks like this: **Definition 3** (Absolute Value)**.**

How can I get the entire thing to be bold and for the period to be a colon?

Comment: I usually use this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185168/3929, see also egregs answer to the same question

Comment: @daleif thank you!!