# The name of my Theorem is not bold when I use default amsthm package settings

Tags: fonts, theorems, amsthm

here is what I have done. I am only doing this minimal example just to make sure that I have not done any customization to override the default setting. However, in the output I get the name of the theorem is not bold. Could anyone please let me know why this happens or maybe how I can resolve this? Thank you very much[image]

Clarification: Thanks to guys who pointed this out; what I meant was that I want the "Name" to be in bold (and overleaf says this is what my tex should generate).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Name]
This is a theorem with a bold name.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE results in the result you show in the image, with "Theorem 1" in bold font. Therefore, the question is unclear.

Comment: Do you want "(Name)" to be in bold as well?

Comment: `(Name)` in regular weight is expected.

Comment: Duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43966/3929

Comment: Yeah that's whay I meant to "samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz"