# Adding a title to theorem environment

Tags: theorems, amsthm

I am trying to use the `theorem` environment in my work as **Sample Problem**.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{mythmstyle}
    {}{}{}{}
    {\bf}
    {}
    {\newline}
    {}
\theoremstyle{mythmstyle}
\newtheorem{mythm}{Sample Problem}[chapter]
\setcounter{chapter}{2}

\begin{document}
\chapter{New Chapter}
\begin{mythm}
    Problem statement goes here. But, where does go title?
\end{mythm}
\end{document}
```

And the output,

[image]

Actually, I need something like this,

[image]

In other words, my **Sample Problem** lacks a **Title**.

**How can I include a title within the theorem environment?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution with `thmtools`, which eases defining new theorem styles:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage{fourier, erewhon, cabin}
\usepackage[table, x11names]{xcolor} \usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools}
\usepackage{microtype} \SetTracking[no ligatures = {f}]{encoding = *}{50}
\declaretheoremstyle[%
headfont=\color{SteelBlue3}\sffamily\bfseries\lsstyle,
within=chapter, headpunct={\medskip}, postheadspace=\newline, notefont=\color{black}\mdseries, notebraces = {\quad}{},spaceabove = 8pt,spacebelow = 8pt]%
{sample}

\declaretheorem[name=Sample Problem, style=sample]{mypb}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{3}

\begin{mypb}[Adding vectors in a drawing, orienteering]
  Show the following assertion is true: %
  \begin{equation*}
    a = a
  \end{equation*}
\end{mypb}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `thmtools` package uses more understandable semantics than `amsthm`. Isn't it?

Comment: I agree with you. Amsthm is OK for simple modifications, but it's better  to supplement it with `thmtools` for more complex layouts. Anyway, personally, I use `ntheorem`,  which is also easier to customise and has an automatic placement of end-of-proof symbols.

Answer (score 0):

The title goes in squared brackets at the beginning of the theorem.

```
\begin{mythm}[Here goes the title]
Problem statement goes here. But, where does go title?
\end{mythm}
```

[image: This is what it looks like]

It doesn't look exactly what your example picture looks like, but as the "Sample Problem 3.1" text is bold making the title also bold wouldn't benefit readability.

Comment: Could you please add a brief explanation?

Comment: yes, of course, I hoped it would be self explanatory.

Comment: @BenjaminH Thanks, but I guess this argument is for theorem source citation and the parentheses are redundant.

Comment: I've seen this usage a lot at my institute. Your question has been asked [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22223/title-of-the-theorem) and was answered the same way. So I suppose this is the way to go.